# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB while Enabling/Disabling TextView#setTextIsSelectable in ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have an activity with `ListView` . Displaying the `TextView` in each list item. Switching the properties of selected position using these methods `EditText#setTextIsSelectable` , `EditText#setEllipsize` & `EditText#setSingleLine` . clicking on 1st item is working good. But while clicking on another item I'm getting `StackOverFlowError`.

Below is my code sample. Please let me know if i do any mistake.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SelectableTextListActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "HistoryActivity";

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//only ListView present in this layout
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);

        String items[] = {"Some Information Some Information Some Information", "Some Information Some Information Some Information", "Some Information Some Information Some Information", "Some Information Some Information Some Information",
                "Some Information Some Information Some Information", "Some Information Some Information Some Information", "Some Information Some Information Some Information", "Some Information Some Information Some Information"};
        final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, items);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: position=" + position);
                myAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private static final String TAG = "HistoryAdapter";
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;
        private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
        private String[] mItems;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
            mItems = items;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public void setSelectedPosition(int mSelectedPosition) {
            this.mSelectedPosition = mSelectedPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectable_text_layout, null, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            String item = getItem(position);

            viewHolder.selectableTV.setText(item);


            if (position == mSelectedPosition) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getView() called with: " + "position = [" + position + "], selected = " + true);
                viewHolder.selectableTV.setTextIsSelectable(true);
                viewHolder.selectableTV.setSingleLine(false);
                viewHolder.selectableTV.setEllipsize(null);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "getView() called with: " + "position = [" + position + "], selected = " + false);
                viewHolder.selectableTV.setTextIsSelectable(false);
                viewHolder.selectableTV.setSingleLine(true);
                viewHolder.selectableTV.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
            }
            return convertView;
        }


        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return mItems[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mItems.length;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            public final TextView selectableTV;

            ViewHolder(View convertView) {
                selectableTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectableTextView);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Layout file :
selectable_text_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectableTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="My app name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the stack trace is

```
D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
at java.lang.Class.isInstance(Class.java:1484)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.getSpans(SpannableStringInternal.java:217)
at android.text.SpannedString.getSpans(SpannedString.java:25)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.<init>(SpannableStringInternal.java:40)
at android.text.SpannableString.<init>(SpannableString.java:30)
at android.widget.TextView.removeSuggestionSpans(TextView.java:4200)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3911)
at android.widget.TextView.getIterableTextForAccessibility(TextView.java:9047)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5450)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5422)
at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(TextView.java:8402)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5293)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5280)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5257)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5226)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAccessibilityEvent(TextView.java:8571)
at android.widget.TextView.onSelectionChanged(TextView.java:7584)
at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7784)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:9478)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringInternal.java:314)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:138)
at android.text.SpannableString.setSpan(SpannableString.java:46)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.<init>(SpannableStringInternal.java:52)
at android.text.SpannableString.<init>(SpannableString.java:30)
at android.widget.TextView.removeSuggestionSpans(TextView.java:4200)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3911)
at android.widget.TextView.getIterableTextForAccessibility(TextView.java:9047)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5450)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5422)
at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(TextView.java:8402)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5293)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5280)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5257)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5226)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAccessibilityEvent(TextView.java:8571)
at android.widget.TextView.onSelectionChanged(TextView.java:7584)
at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7784)
at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:9478)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringInternal.java:314)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:138)
at android.text.SpannableString.setSpan(SpannableString.java:46)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.<init>(SpannableStringInternal.java:52)
at android.text.SpannableString.<init>(SpannableString.java:30)
at android.widget.TextView.removeSuggestionSpans(TextView.java:4200)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3926)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3911)
at android.widget.TextView.getIterableTextForAccessibility(TextView.java:9047)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5450)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5422)
at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(TextView.java:8402)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5293)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5280)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5257)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5226)
at android.widget.TextView.sendAccessibilityEvent(TextView.java:8

09-13 00:48:45.483 8705-8705/club.apptu.edittextlocalhistory D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 16156172
09-13 00:48:45.483 8705-8705/club.apptu.edittextlocalhistory E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
09-13 00:48:45.484 8705-8705/club.apptu.edittextlocalhistory E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4144)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :**

I'm getting problem when calling `notifyDatasetChanged` in  `ListView#onItemClickListener` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for my problem. I removed `ViewHolder` pattern in `MyAdapter` like

```
private static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "HistoryAdapter";
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
    private String[] mItems;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] mItems) {
        this.mItems = mItems;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }



    public void setSelectedPosition(int mSelectedPosition) {
        this.mSelectedPosition = mSelectedPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectable_text_layout, null, false);
        TextView selectableTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selectableTextView);

        selectableTV.setText(getItem(position));

        if (position == mSelectedPosition) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getView() called with: " + "position = [" + position + "], selected = " + true);
            selectableTV.setTextIsSelectable(true);
            selectableTV.setSingleLine(false);
            selectableTV.setEllipsize(null);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "getView() called with: " + "position = [" + position + "], selected = " + false);
            selectableTV.setTextIsSelectable(false);
            selectableTV.setSingleLine(true);
            selectableTV.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mItems[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.length;
    }
}
```

But **still didn't find the the reason for the problem when using `ViewHolder` pattern**.If anybody find the reason let me know.

Answer (score 4):

i was calling `onBackPressed()` recursively and that caused `StackOverFlowError` for me.

Comment: similar kind of issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was too much of log.i statements, where gson was used to convert array to string for logging purpose. When I removed all the logs, the stackOverflowError went away.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find the error is use a lot of `logcat` in your code and find where the `logcat` is not showing.
But you can try to change your code like this:

1. delete the `inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);` in MyAdapter constructor
2. move it in `getview` method like this:

   ```
   if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
       convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectable_text_layout, null,false);</br>
       viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
       convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. that is not the actual problem. Even though I tried But the issue still not resolved.

Comment: The error occurred when I call notifyDatasetChanged() , but I can't find problem.

Comment: what is happening if you comment: myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?  first solution: replace myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); to ((MyAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); if it's not work : try the second solution:  runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
})

Answer (score 0):

To much of iteration on list scroll will produce this error.. Avoid that...