# App crashes when I uncheck all items using custom adapter and listView

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to check items from a list of `Tweet` :

```
public class Tweet implements Parcelable {
private int color;
private String pseudo;
private String text;

public Tweet(int color, String pseudo, String text) {
    this.color = color;
    this.pseudo = pseudo;
    this.text = text;
}

public int getColor(){ return this.color; }
public String getPseudo(){ return this.pseudo; }
public String getText(){ return this.text; }

public int setColor(){ return this.color; }
public String setPseudo(){ return this.pseudo; }
public String setText(){ return this.text; }

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(pseudo);
    out.writeString(text);
    out.writeInt(color);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Tweet> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Tweet>() {
    public Tweet createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Tweet(in);
    }

    public Tweet[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Tweet[size];
    }
};

protected Tweet(Parcel in) {
    pseudo = in.readString();
    text = in.readString();
    color = in.readInt();
}
}
```

Here the code of the main Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView _m_list_view;

TweetAdapter _m_tweet_adaptateur;
List<Tweet> _m_tweets;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _m_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    _m_tweets = genererTweets();

    _m_tweet_adaptateur = new TweetAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            _m_tweets, _m_list_view.getChoiceMode());
    _m_list_view.setAdapter(_m_tweet_adaptateur);

    _m_list_view.setClickable(true);
    _m_list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent tmp_intent;
            // lancement 2nde activité avec un seul item
            tmp_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTweetDetailActivity.class);
            //startActivityForResult(tmp_intent, 0);*
            tmp_intent.putExtra("tweet",(Tweet)_m_list_view.getItemAtPosition(position));
            startActivity(tmp_intent);
        }
    });
    _m_list_view.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            _m_list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            _m_tweet_adaptateur.setChoiseMode(_m_list_view.getChoiceMode());
            _m_list_view.setItemChecked(i, true);
            return true;
        }
    });

    _m_list_view.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean b) {

            updateActionModeTitle(actionMode);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_tweet, menu);
            actionMode.setCustomView(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.menu_select_tweet, null));
            updateActionModeTitle(actionMode);
            return(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //quand on appui sur ok dans le menu
                case R.id.item_select_multi_tweet:
                  /*  int ii;
                    int tmp_key;
                    Intent tmp_intent;
                    ArrayList tmp_list;
                    SparseBooleanArray tmp_checked_list;
                    tmp_list = new ArrayList();
                    tmp_checked_list = _m_list_view.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    if (tmp_checked_list != null) {
                        for (ii = 0; ii < tmp_checked_list.size(); ii++) {
                            tmp_key = tmp_checked_list.keyAt(ii);
                            if (tmp_checked_list.get(tmp_key)) {
                                tmp_list.add(_m_list_view.getItemAtPosition(tmp_key));
                            }
                        }
                        tmp_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowTweetDetailActivity.class);
                        //startActivityForResult(tmp_intent, 0);*
                        tmp_intent.putExtra("tweet",tmp_list);
                        startActivity(tmp_intent);
                    }
                    return true;*/
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            _m_list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
            _m_tweet_adaptateur.setChoiseMode(_m_list_view.getChoiceMode());
            _m_list_view.setAdapter(_m_tweet_adaptateur);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context_menu_tweet, menu);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private void updateActionModeTitle(ActionMode in_action_mode) {
    int tmp_count;
    TextView tmp_textview;

    tmp_count = _m_list_view.getCheckedItemCount();
    tmp_textview = (TextView) in_action_mode.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.context_menu_select_tweet_textview);
    tmp_textview.setText(tmp_count + " " + "Tweet" + ((tmp_count > 1) ? "s" : ""));

    if (tmp_count < _m_list_view.getCount()) {
        ((CheckBox) in_action_mode.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.context_menu_select_tweet_checkbox)).setChecked(false);
    }
    else {
        ((CheckBox) in_action_mode.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.context_menu_select_tweet_checkbox)).setChecked(true);
    }
}

public void onSelectAllTweet(View in_view) {
    int ii;
    boolean tmp_checked;

    tmp_checked = ((CheckBox) in_view).isChecked();

    if (tmp_checked) {
        for (ii=0; ii<_m_list_view.getCount(); ii++) {
            _m_list_view.setItemChecked(ii, true);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (ii=0; ii<_m_list_view.getCount(); ii++) {
            _m_list_view.setItemChecked(ii, false);
        }
    }
}

    private List<Tweet> genererTweets(){
    List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    tweets.add(new Tweet(Color.BLACK, "Florent", "Mon premier tweet !"));
    tweets.add(new Tweet(Color.BLUE, "Kevin", "C'est ici que ça se passe !"));
    tweets.add(new Tweet(Color.GREEN, "Logan", "Que c'est beau..."));
    tweets.add(new Tweet(Color.RED, "Mathieu", "Il est quelle heure ??"));
    tweets.add(new Tweet(Color.GRAY, "Willy", "On y est presque"));
    return tweets;
}
```

And my CustomAdapter :

```
public class TweetAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private int _m_choice_mode;
private List<Tweet> _m_tweet_list;
private Context _m_context;
//tweets est la liste des models à afficher
public TweetAdapter(Context context, List<Tweet> tweets, int in_choice_mode) {
    _m_choice_mode = in_choice_mode;
    _m_tweet_list = tweets;
    _m_context = context;
}

public void setChoiseMode(int in_choise_mode) {
    _m_choice_mode = in_choise_mode;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return _m_tweet_list.size();
}

@Override
public Tweet getItem(int position) {
    return _m_tweet_list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(_m_context).inflate(R.layout.row_tweet,parent, false);
    }

    TweetViewHolder viewHolder = (TweetViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    if(viewHolder == null){
        viewHolder = new TweetViewHolder();
        viewHolder.m_selector = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.selector);
        viewHolder.pseudo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pseudotweet);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.texttweet);
        viewHolder.avatar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatartweet);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    //getItem(position) va récupérer l'item [position] de la List<Tweet> tweets
    Tweet tweet = getItem(position);

    //il ne reste plus qu'à remplir notre vue
    viewHolder.pseudo.setText(tweet.getPseudo());
    viewHolder.text.setText(tweet.getText());
    viewHolder.avatar.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(tweet.getColor()));

    if (_m_choice_mode == ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL) {
        viewHolder.m_selector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder.m_selector.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class TweetViewHolder{
    public ImageView m_selector;
    public TextView pseudo;
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView avatar;

}
```

My problem comes when i uncheck all the items while the ListView is in the `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` mode (this mode is set when we longClicked on an item). When i uncheck the last checked item, the `onDestroyActionMode` method, more exactly line `_m_list_view.setChoiceMode(...)`, gives me an error and the application crashes without message.
Here the log :

```
10-25 15:38:43.396 31949-31949/com.example.vvigie.testappactires D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:82)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1603)
                                                                          at com.example.vvigie.testappactires.MainActivity$3.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:135)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:8355)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3963)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:179)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onDestroyActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1806)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.finish(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1007)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:82)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1603)
                                                                          at com.example.vvigie.testappactires.MainActivity$3.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:135)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:8355)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3963)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:179)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onDestroyActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1806)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.finish(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1007)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:82)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1603)
                                                                          at com.example.vvigie.testappactires.MainActivity$3.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:135)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:8355)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3963)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:179)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onDestroyActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1806)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.finish(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1007)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:82)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1603)
                                                                          at com.example.vvigie.testappactires.MainActivity$3.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:135)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:8355)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3963)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:179)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV9.onDestroyActionMode(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1806)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.finish(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1007)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper.finish(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:82)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.java:1603)
                                                                          at com.example.vvigie.testappactires.MainActivity$3.onDestroyActionMode(MainActivity.java:135)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(AbsListView.java:8355)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:3963)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onDestroyActionMode(SupportActionModeWrapper.java:179)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCom
```

I don't understand why this line bring this error... Can you please help me.
Sorry for my "french" english.

EDIT : The solution is in comments, thanks !

Comment: can u move viewHolder.pseudo.setText(tweet.getPseudo()); else of null.. its going to set twice... also try to run your app in hierarchy viewer to see how many views are displayed?  https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html also take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066986/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-stack-size-8mb-while-enabling-disabling-textviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an infinite call loop. This line `_m_list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);` results in `AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener#onDestroyActionMode()` getting called, which calls the first line again, etc.

The summary is that you shouldn't call `_m_list_view.setChoiceMode()` in `onDestroyActionMode()`, or at least, you don't need to set it to `NONE`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i comment the line, the checkboxes remain on the view because the mode of the adapter is not set to `NONE`... And when i manually set the mode as `NONE` : `_m_tweet_adaptateur.setChoiseMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);`, the checkboxes won't appear when i long click on an item.

Comment: When should the checkboxes be removed? I think probably you want to do this from a different callback.

Comment: The checkboxes should be removed when no items are selected. In the adapter i use :  `if (_m_choice_mode == ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL) {
        viewHolder.m_selector.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder.m_selector.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }`

Comment: maybe make the checkbox visibility decision based on the count of checked items instead of the choice mode?

Alternative would be to set the choice mode in onCheckedChanged or similar.

Comment: I put                 `if(_m_list_view.getCheckedItemCount()==0) {
                    _m_list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
                }` in `onItemcheckedStateChanged` and remove `_m_list_view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);` from  `onDestroyActionMode` and now it seems correct. But there is another issue, when i use the back button of my phone or back button of the menu, the checkboxes are still there

Comment: These seem like separate issues from "why is this crashing?" You may want to open a new question.